Array to string conversion error in php when retriving records from Ganache
I am creating a web-based Blockchain E-health system using Laravel for frontend and backend, Solidity & Truffle for creating smart contracts and Ganache for deploying smart contracts. I am able to create patient records and transfer them to my blockchain network but I can't retrieve all the patient records from the blockchain and display them in a table.
The array to string conversion error
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.17;

contract PatientRecords {

    // Structure to store patient details
    struct Patient {
        uint patientId;         // Unique identifier for the patient
        string fullNames;       // Full names of the patient
        uint phone;             // Phone number
        string email;           // Email address
        string insuranceDetails; // Insurance details
        string gender;          // Gender of the patient
        uint dob;               // Date of birth (as a Unix timestamp)
        string addressDetails;  // Physical address of the patient
    }

    // Mapping to store patients by their ID
    mapping(uint => Patient) private patients;

    // Array to store all patient IDs for enumeration
    uint[] private patientIds;

    // Event to notify when a new patient is added
    event PatientAdded(uint patientId, string fullNames, string email);

    // Function to add a new patient
    function addPatient(
        uint _patientId,
        string memory _fullNames,
        uint _phone,
        string memory _email,
        string memory _insuranceDetails,
        string memory _gender,
        uint _dob,
        string memory _addressDetails
    ) public {
        require(patients[_patientId].patientId == 0, "Patient with this ID already exists.");

        // Add patient details
        patients[_patientId] = Patient(
            _patientId,
            _fullNames,
            _phone,
            _email,
            _insuranceDetails,
            _gender,
            _dob,
            _addressDetails
        );

        // Track the patient ID
        patientIds.push(_patientId);

        // Emit the event
        emit PatientAdded(_patientId, _fullNames, _email);
    }

    // Function to get a patient's details by ID
    function getPatient(uint _patientId) public view returns (
        uint,
        string memory,
        uint,
        string memory,
        string memory,
        string memory,
        uint,
        string memory
    ) {
        require(patients[_patientId].patientId != 0, "Patient not found.");

        Patient memory patient = patients[_patientId];
        return (
            patient.patientId,
            patient.fullNames,
            patient.phone,
            patient.email,
            patient.insuranceDetails,
            patient.gender,
            patient.dob,
            patient.addressDetails
        );
    }

    // Function to get all patient IDs
    function getAllPatientIds() public view returns (uint[] memory) {
        return patientIds;
    }

    // Function to check if a patient exists by ID
    function patientExists(uint _patientId) public view returns (bool) {
        return patients[_patientId].patientId != 0;
    }
}

Admin Controller
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Admin as ModelsAdmin;
use App\Models\Appointments;
use App\Models\Department;
use App\Models\Hospital;
use App\Models\HP;
use App\Models\Patients;
use App\Models\Referral;
use App\Notifications\ReferralRequestNotification;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Web3\Contract;
use Web3\Web3;

class Admin extends Controller
{
  //
  private $web3;
  private $patientContract;
  private $patientContractAddress = "0xf91d57278089Fae6c832cc0Ce6962900398BA7c2";

  private $patientAbi = '[
    {
      "anonymous": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "indexed": false,
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "patientId",
          "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
          "indexed": false,
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "fullNames",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "indexed": false,
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "email",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "name": "PatientAdded",
      "type": "event"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "_patientId",
          "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "_fullNames",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "_phone",
          "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "_email",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "_insuranceDetails",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "_gender",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "_dob",
          "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "_addressDetails",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "name": "addPatient",
      "outputs": [],
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "_patientId",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "name": "getPatient",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function",
      "constant": true
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "getAllPatientIds",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "uint256[]",
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256[]"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function",
      "constant": true
    },
    {
      "inputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "_patientId",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "name": "patientExists",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "bool",
          "name": "",
          "type": "bool"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function",
      "constant": true
    }
  ]';

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->web3 = new Web3('http://127.0.0.1:7545'); // Ganache RPC server
    $this->patientContract = new Contract($this->web3->provider, $this->patientAbi);
  }

  public function registerhos()
  {

    return view('Admin/hospRegister');
  }

  public function proceed(Request $request)
  {


    $hos = new Hospital();
    $hos->Hospital_Name = $request->health;
    $hos->Address = $request->Address;
    $hos->save();

    event(new Registered($hos));
    Auth::guard('hospital')->login($hos);
    return redirect('admin/register')->with('success', 'Hospital registered successfully');
  }

  public function registerpage()
  {

    return view('Admin/adminRegister');
  }

  public function register(Request $request)
  {


    $adm = new ModelsAdmin();
    $hosp = Auth::guard('hospital')->user();

    if (!$hosp) {
      return redirect()->route('hos')->with('warning', 'You must be working in a health facility to register as an admin.');
    }

    $adm->AdminID = $request->adminID;
    $adm->Full_Names = $request->fullnames;
    $adm->Email = $request->email;
    $adm->Phone = $request->phone;
    $adm->HospitalID = $hosp->HospitalID;
    $adm->Role = $request->role;
    $adm->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $adm->save();

    event(new Registered($adm));

    Auth::guard('admin')->login($adm);
    return redirect('admin/login')->with('success', 'Admin registered successfully');
  }

  public function loginpage()
  {

    return view('Admin/adminLogin');
  }

  public function login(Request $request)
  {
    // Validate the form data
    $credentials =  $request->validate([
      'AdminID' => 'required',
      'password' => 'required',
    ]);



    // Attempt to authenticate the admin with the provided credentials
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials)) {
      // Regenerate session to avoid session fixation attacks
      $request->session()->regenerate();

      // Redirect the admin to the appointments page
      return redirect()->intended('admin/appointments')->with('success', 'You have logged in successfully');
    } else {
      // Authentication failed, redirect back to login with an error message
      return redirect('admin/login')->with('error', [
        'AdminID' => 'Invalid AdminID or password',
      ])->withInput($request->only('AdminID')); // Keep the AdminID field filled
    }
  }


  public function patientform()
  {

    return view('Admin/patientRegister');
  }

  public function patientRegister(Request $request)
  {

    // Save patient data to the database
    $patient = new Patients();
    $patient->PatientID = $request->PatientID;
    $patient->Full_Names = $request->Full_Names;
    $patient->Phone = $request->Phone;
    $patient->Email = $request->Email;
    $patient->InsuranceDetails = $request->Insurance;
    $patient->Gender = $request->Gender;
    $patient->DOB = $request->dob;
    $patient->Address = $request->Address;
    $patient->save();

    try {
      // Call the blockchain contract to register the patient
      $this->patientContract->at($this->patientContractAddress)->send(
        'addPatient',
        $request->PatientID,
        $request->Full_Names,
        $request->Phone,
        $request->Email,
        $request->Insurance,
        $request->Gender,
        strtotime($request->dob), // Convert DOB to Unix timestamp
        $request->Address,
        [
          'from' => '0xB013cFb025045a2c7FAe68890BDAD0E6041721b0', // Replace with the sender's blockchain address
          'gas' => 3000000, // Adjust gas limit if needed
        ],
        function ($err, $result) {
          if ($err !== null) {
            throw new \Exception($err->getMessage());
          }
        }
      );
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      // Handle blockchain errors and rollback database changes
      $patient->delete(); // Remove the saved patient if blockchain fails
      return redirect('admin/appointments')->with('error', ['blockchain' => 'Failed to register patient on blockchain: ' . $e->getMessage()]);
    }

    // Redirect back with success message
    return redirect('admin/appointments')->with('message', 'Patient registered successfully!');
  }


  public function appointpage()
  {
    $contractInstance = $this->patientContract->at($this->patientContractAddress);

    // Fetch all patient IDs
    $patientIds = [];
    $contractInstance->call('getAllPatientIds', [], function ($err, $result) use (&$patientIds) {
      if ($err !== null) {
        throw new \Exception('Error fetching patient IDs: ' . $err->getMessage());
      }

      // Process the returned result to extract patient IDs
      foreach ($result as $patientIdArray) {
        if (is_array($patientIdArray)) {
          foreach ($patientIdArray as $patientId) {
            // Ensure patientId is a scalar value before using
            if (method_exists($patientId, 'toString')) {
              $patientIds[] = (string) $patientId->toString(); // Ensure it's a string
            } else {
              Log::warning('Invalid format for patient ID.', ['patientId' => $patientId]);
            }
          }
        } elseif (method_exists($patientIdArray, 'toString')) {
          $patientIds[] = (string) $patientIdArray->toString(); // Ensure it's a string
        } else {
          Log::warning('Unexpected patient ID format.', ['patientIdArray' => $patientIdArray]);
        }
      }
    });


    // Validate extracted patient IDs
    if (empty($patientIds)) {
      Log::info('No patient IDs were fetched from the blockchain.');
    }

    // Fetch patient details for each ID
    $patients = [];
    foreach ($patientIds as $patientId) {
      if (!is_scalar($patientId)) {
        Log::error('Invalid patient ID encountered, skipping.', ['patientId' => $patientId]);
        continue; // Skip invalid patient IDs
      }

      $contractInstance->call('getPatient', [(string)$patientId], function ($err, $result) use (&$patients, $patientId) {
        if ($err !== null) {
            throw new \Exception("Error fetching details for patient ID {$patientId}: " . $err->getMessage());
        }
    

        // Validate and map the result to a patient array
        if (is_array($result) && count($result) >= 8) {
          $patients[] = [
            'patientId' => (int)$result[0]->toString(),  // Convert BigInteger to int
            'fullNames' => $result[1] ?? 'N/A',          // Full names
            'phone' => $result[2] ?? 'N/A',              // Phone number
            'email' => $result[3] ?? 'N/A',              // Email
            'insuranceDetails' => $result[4] ?? 'N/A',   // Insurance details
            'gender' => $result[5] ?? 'N/A',             // Gender
            'dob' => isset($result[6]) ? date('Y-m-d', (int)$result[6]->toString()) : 'N/A', // Date of birth
            'addressDetails' => $result[7] ?? 'N/A',     // Address details
          ];
        } else {
          Log::warning("Invalid result format for patient ID {$patientId}.", ['result' => $result]);
        }
      });
    }

    // Debugging: Log the patients array to ensure it's correctly structured
    Log::info('Fetched patients from blockchain', ['patients' => $patients]);

    // Get authenticated admin details and follow-up notifications
    $adm = Auth::guard('admin')->user();
    $followups = $adm->notifications;

    // Return the view with patients and follow-ups
    return view('Admin/appointmentlist', compact('patients', 'followups'));
  }








  public function patientsch($patientid)
  {
    // Find the patient by ID or handle not found scenario
    $patient = Patients::find($patientid);

    // Pass the patient object to the view for scheduling
    if ($patient) {
      return view('Admin/schedule', compact('patient'));
    }

    return redirect('admin/appointments')->withErrors('Patient not found.');
  }



  public function ScheduleAppointment(Request $request, $patientid)
  {
    // Check if the patient exists before proceeding
    $patient = Patients::find($patientid);

    if (!$patient) {
      return redirect('admin/appointments')->withErrors('Patient not found.');
    }


    // Create new appointment for the patient
    $app = new Appointments();
    $app->ProviderID = $request->Provider;
    $app->PatientID = $patientid;  // Use $patientid from the route
    $app->reason = $request->Reason;
    $app->status = "Waiting";
    $app->save();

    return redirect('admin/appointments/')->with('success', 'Appointment scheduled successfully');
  }


  public function viewstaff()
  {

    $adm = Auth::guard('admin')->user();
    $staff = HP::where('HospitalID', $adm->HospitalID)->get();
    return view('Admin/viewstaff', compact('staff'));
  }

  public function registstaff()
  {

    // Get the authenticated admin
    $adm = Auth::guard('admin')->user();

    // Retrieve the departments for the admin's hospital
    $departments = Department::where('HospitalID', $adm->HospitalID)->get();

    return view('Admin/staffregister', compact('departments'));
  }

  public function registerstaff(Request $request)
  {

    $hp = new HP();
    $adm = Auth::guard('admin')->user();
    $hosp = Hospital::where('HospitalID', $adm->HospitalID)->first();
    if ($hosp) {  // Check if the hospital exists
      $hp->ProviderID = $request->ProviderID;
      $hp->Full_Names = $request->Full_Names;
      $hp->Specialization = $request->Specialization;
      $hp->Email = $request->Email;
      $hp->Phone = $request->Phone;
      $hp->HospitalID = $hosp->HospitalID;
      $hp->DepartmentID = $request->Department_Name;
      $hp->password = bcrypt($request->password);
      $hp->save();

      return redirect('admin/viewstaff')->with('success', 'Staff added successfully');
    }

    return redirect('admin/viewstaff')->with('error', 'Hospital not found');
  }

  public function viewdep()
  {

    return view('Admin/viewdep');
  }

  public function registdep()
  {

    return view('Admin/depregister');
  }

  public function registerdep(Request $request)
  {
    $adm = Auth::guard('admin')->user();
    $hosp = Hospital::where('HospitalID', $adm->HospitalID)->first();  // Retrieve a single hospital record

    if ($hosp) {  // Check if the hospital exists
      $dep = new Department();
      $dep->HospitalID = $hosp->HospitalID;  // Assign the integer HospitalID
      $dep->Department_Name = $request->Department_Name;  // Assign department name from the form
      $dep->save();

      return redirect('admin/view_departments')->with('success', 'Department added successfully');
    }

    return redirect('admin/view_departments')->with('error', 'Hospital not found');
  }

  public function referralforms() {}

  public function makeReferralRequest(Request $request, $patientId, $receivingAdminId)
  {
    $referringAdmin = Auth::guard('admin')->user();
    $referral = new Referral();


    $receivingAdmin = ModelsAdmin::findOrFail($receivingAdminId);
    $receivingAdmin->notify(new ReferralRequestNotification($referral));

    return back()->with('message', 'Referral request sent successfully.');
  }


  public function ViewMedicalLogs() {}

  public function ExportLog() {}
}

web.php
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use App\Http\Controllers\Provider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::middleware(['web'])->group(function () {
    // ...
    #Admin Login routes
    Route::get('hospital/register', [Admin::class, 'registerhos'])->name('hos');
    Route::post('hospital/register', [Admin::class, 'proceed']);

    
    Route::get('provider/login', [Provider::class, 'loginpage'])->name('log');
    Route::post('provider/login', [Provider::class, 'login']);
});

Route::middleware(['hospital'])->group(function () {

    #Admin register routes
    Route::get('admin/register', [Admin::class, 'registerpage'])->name('admr');
    Route::post('admin/register', [Admin::class, 'register']);

    #Admin Login routes
    Route::get('admin/login', [Admin::class, 'loginpage'])->name('adm');
    Route::post('admin/login', [Admin::class, 'login']);

    Route::middleware(['admin'])->group(function () {
        // ...

        #Admin Login routes
        Route::get('admin/appointments', [Admin::class, 'appointpage']);

        Route::get('admin/registerpatient', [Admin::class, 'patientform'])->name('pat');
        Route::post('admin/registerpatient', [Admin::class, 'patientRegister']);

        Route::get('admin/appointments/schedule/{id}', [Admin::class, 'patientsch'])->name('app');
        Route::post('admin/appointments/schedule/{id}', [Admin::class, 'ScheduleAppointment']);

        Route::get('admin/viewstaff', [Admin::class, 'viewstaff']);

        Route::get('admin/registerstaff', [Admin::class, 'registstaff'])->name('rstaff');
        Route::post('admin/registerstaff', [Admin::class, 'registerstaff']);

        Route::get('admin/view_departments', [Admin::class, 'viewdep']);

        Route::get('admin/add_department', [Admin::class, 'registdep'])->name('dep');
        Route::post('admin/add_department', [Admin::class, 'registerdep']);
    });

    Route::middleware(['provider'])->group(function () {

        Route::get('provider/dashboard', [Provider::class, 'dashboard']);
        Route::post('provider/patientcheckin/{id}', [Provider::class, 'checkin']);

        Route::get('provider/diagnose/{id}', [Provider::class, 'diagpage'])->name('diag');
        Route::post('provider/diagnose/{id}', [Provider::class, 'saveDiagnosis']);

        Route::get('provider/dreports', [Provider::class, 'Dreports']);

        Route::get('provider/addmedreport/{id}', [Provider::class, 'medpage']);
        Route::post('provider/medreport/{id}', [Provider::class, 'saveMedRecord']);
    });
});


At the foreach, before the if (!is_scalar($patientId)) { check, add dd($patientId); to see what the $patientId contains. Based on the error, it looks like $patientId appears to be an array, not a string?
